# Jquery - Check Radio Button, Get Specific Label Content

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have spent hours and hours over the last few days trying just about every Stack Overflow snippet I can find to hack this together myself but nothing has worked the way I need it. At this stage, I'm hoping one of you will kindly help me out.

Objective:

I have a list of radio buttons displayed on a order form. I want to extract specific label content from the checked radio input only and save it to a variable i.e "3 Product Name" or "1 Product Name".

```js
$("input:radio").click(function() {
  var label_description = this.parentElement.outerText;
  alert(label_description);
});

//Goal- Extract specific label content from checked radio input e.g "3 Product Name" or "1 Product Name"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="12374747">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">3 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">4 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">6 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">1 Product Name</label>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1t1edf8v/5/

As you can see, all I have is working code that pulls out the full label content and the price. I understand why this is happening, I just haven't been able to isolate what I need.

Thanks so much for any help with this!

Comment: you mean, you don't want entire text after clicking on radio btn?

Comment: Correct, right now  it pulls out the price and the full label. I only want specific content from the label e.g Radio 1 checked alert "3 Product Name"

Comment: Please, in future, place your ([MCVE]) code in your question, in order that users don't have to visit external sites to see your HTML in order to understand what your JavaScript is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up David, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, use querySelector:

```
 alert(this.parentElement.querySelector("[data-cf-product-name]").outerText)
```

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1t1edf8v/3/

Please note I am using **attribute selector inside querySelector** function, if you want you can use some other selector.

To pull out string "3 product name" or any other string only, **you can use split function or regEx**. You just need some pattern here.

For eg,

```
var text = this.parentElement.querySelector("[data-cf-product-name]").outerText;
var selected = (text.split("-"))[0].trim();
alert(selected);
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1t1edf8v/8/

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, this isolates the label content only which is great. However, I need to pull out specific content from that label. Thoughts?

Comment: Give me an example what you want to pull out... I will try to help

Comment: Examples: 

If Radio 1 checked - Pull out "3 Product Name",
If Radio 2 checked - Pull out "4 Product Name",
If Radio 3 checked - Pull out "6 Product Name",
If Radio 4 checked - Pull out "1 Product Name"

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your help Nitesh! You wouldn't believe how much time I spent trying to do this myself!

Comment: Opening this up again as this code does not work in Firefox. Took a while to pinpoint that this is the problem code and sure enough the JSFiddle is not working in FF.

Comment: Heyy Paul,
Please find this link with updated code that works in FF also.
http://jsfiddle.net/1t1edf8v/13/

I am sorry for not checking but I think this is a very minor issue. It is easily solvable if you try to find such an issue.
Happy coding

Comment: Hey, thanks Nitesh. I can see the change you made now. Not exactly sure why this was affecting FF so much but it's all working great now! Thanks again!

Comment: No issues man... just wanted to request you to find such little issues by yoursef. It will help you further in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
  `$(this).siblings('label').HTML()`

But a better way is to assign some id to your div or label so you can differentiate it later.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code you posted; your HTML repeated a number of elements which have the same `id`: this is invalid, as an `id` must uniquely identify one single element in the document (if you want to share a common identifier use either a class-name, or a custom `data-*` attribute). The consequence of the shared `id` attributes meant that the `<label>` elements, when clicked, could only select the first element with that particular `id` (it's perfectly valid for one `<input>` element to be associated with multiple `<label>` elements).

Having changed the `id` attributes to be unique, and the `for` attribute of the `<label>` elements to associate that given `<label>` with the correct `<input>`, the following becomes possible:

```js
// using attribute-selection to identify the <input> elements
// whose 'type' attribute is equal to 'radio', and binding the
// anonymous function of the on() method as the event-handler
// for the 'change' event:
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {

  // using the 'let' statement to create the variable
  // 'productName,' and finding the first <label> element
  // associated with the changed radio-element, retrieving
  // the textContent of that <label> and splitting that
  // text on the '-' character:
  let productName = this.labels[0].textContent.split('-');

  // if we have a truthy productName variable:
  if (productName) {
    // we retrieve the first part of the Array returned
    // by String.prototype.split(), trim that text to
    // remove leading and trailing white-space and then
    // log it to the console:
    console.log(productName[0].trim());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="12374747">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">3 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-02" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-02" data-cf-product-name="true">4 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-03" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-03" data-cf-product-name="true">6 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-04" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-04" data-cf-product-name="true">1 Product Name</label>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2qso6mkb/).

Of course, with plain JavaScript/the DOM API, the above is also perfectly possible:

```js
function retrieveLabelText() {

  // 'this' is passed from EventTarget.addEventListener(),
  // here we again retrieve the first <label> element
  // associated with the changed <input> element,
  // retrieve the textContent of that element and then
  // split the String into an Array using
  // String.prototype.split():
  let text = this.labels[0].textContent.split('-');

  // if we have a truthy 'text' value:
  if (text) {

    // we trim the first element of the Array of
    // Strings, and log that trimmed String to the
    // console:
    console.log(text[0].trim());
  }
}

// here we retrieve all elements in the document that match
// CSS selector, which searches for all <input> elements
// whose 'type' is equal to 'radio', the returned NodeList
// is passed to Array.from(), which converts the Array-like
// NodeList into an Array, with access to the Array methods:
let = radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'));

// here we iterate over the Array of <input> elements using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
radios.forEach(

  // 'radio' is the current radio <input> element of the
  // Array of elements over which we're iterating,
  // here we use an Arrow function to add an event-listener
  // to the current <input> element, using the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() method to bind the named
  // function ('retrieveLabelText') as the event-handler
  // for the 'change' event:
  radio => radio.addEventListener('change', retrieveLabelText)
);
```

```html
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-01" name="purchase[product_id]" value="12374747">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-01" data-cf-product-name="true">3 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-02" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-02" data-cf-product-name="true">4 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-03" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-03" data-cf-product-name="true">6 Product Name - Text here</label>
</div>

<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
  <input type="radio" id="lbl-04" name="purchase[product_id]" value="839909">
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$X.XX</div>
  <label for="lbl-04" data-cf-product-name="true">1 Product Name</label>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2qso6mkb/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors (`[attribute=value]`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
  - [`let` Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed helpful reply. Learnt a lot here! Unfortunately I am at the mercy of the code that is on this page and can only manipulate it with Jquery. I have reopened this question up as the previously accepted answer does not work on Firefox. The search goes on.